# How to inject a datasource with autocommit on or off whether a method is run inside a transaction or not

Tags: java, guice, jooq, apache-commons-dbcp

I have got:

- a DAO class in JOOQ that in its constructor takes a `javax.sql.DataSource`, which is injected by Guice
- a service class that calls the methods from the DAO class

I want to:

- be able to annotate **a few** methods inside the service class as methods requiring a transaction

Possible solution: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/master/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-spring-guice-example i.d.:

- a method interceptor invoked when a method is annotated with the `Transactional` annotation
- the method interceptor calls `rollback()` if there were exceptions or `commit()` if everything was fine
- Guice *provides* a `javax.sql.DataSource` (BoneCP pooled connection)
- the BoneCP pooled connections have the `defaultAutoCommit` attribute set to `false`

Finally, my question:

- I want the datasource with `autocommit` set to `false` to be injected into **all the methods** that are called from the method annotated with  `@Transactional`, in all the other cases the datasource with `autocommit` set to `true`

How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple but not elegant way: create two DataSource instances and inject appropriately.

There is also a bit more complex way with a single DataSource instance. Roughly:

1. AutoCommit is a property of java.sql.Connection and there is a setter for it.
2. Implement org.jooq.ConnectionProvider to make JOOQ use your DataSource instance.
3. This ConnectionProvider implementation will have a special method, e.g. startTransaction() that can create a connection with autocommit=false and cache it in a ThreadLocal member. I.e.

   ```
   Connection conn = dataSource.createConnection();
   conn.setAutoCommit(false);
   threadLocal.set(conn);
   return conn;
   ```
4. ConnectionProvider.acquire() will do smth like (simplified version):

   ```
   return threadLocal.get() != null ? 
          threadLocal.get() : 
          dataSource.createConnection();
   ```
5. Other two "special" methods would be commit() and rollback() - they will do a corresponding operation on the cached connection, close the connection and remove it from threadLocal.
6. The @Transactional method interceptor will call the "special" methods

   ```
   try {
     connectionProvider.startTransaction();
     interceptedMethod.invoke();
     connectionProvider.commit();
   } catch (Exception e) {
     connectionProvider.rollback();
   }
   ```

Essentially, this is the most simple transaction manager.